# jScroll callback to fade in new content

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade

I am trying to fade in the new content loaded by jScroll with the callback option. This is what I've tried so far, but with no success.

**CSS**

```
.jscroll-added {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
 function neueFade() {
     jQuery('.jscroll-added').delay(1000).animate({
         opacity: 1
     }, 700);
 };

 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery('.container').jscroll({
         debug: false,
         loadingHtml: '<img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" />',
         padding: 0,
         nextSelector: '.prev-posts-link a',
         contentSelector: '.container',
         pagingSelector: '',
         callback: neueFade,
     });
 });
```

Comment: CSS= 
.jscroll-added {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to hide the element first, before you call the animation. Also, if you try to animate by selecting `.jscroll-added`, you will animate every content delivered so far. To get it right, you have to target only the element that was just added:

```js
function neueFade() {
    $(this).hide().fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by modifying the script file **jquery.jscroll.js** version 2.3.4 as follows:

Line 156: add ".hide()" after ".last()".

```
$inner.find('div.jscroll-added').last().hide().load( ....
```

Line 169: add ".fadeIn()".

```
}).fadeIn(1000);
```

I tried this and it is working perfect.

Comment: Although this might work, it's best if we find a way that doesn't involve changing the source code of a library, because later when we decide to upgrade it to a newer version we will have to deal with tracking and reapplying all the customization done over time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#comments_area').jscroll({
        autoTrigger: true,
        nextSelector: 'a.jscroll-next:last',
        contentSelector: '#area_main_comment',
        callback: function(){ $('#comments_area').hide(0).fadeIn(2000); comment_active(); }
    });
```